# How to insert input to mysqladmin on command line?

Tags: mysql, mysqladmin

I'd like to automatize the initialization process of the `MySQL`. At the end of the initialization process, I need to change the password of the database, using `mysqladmin -uroot password`. But to automatize this, I need to type a new password manualy.

`echo -e "newpassword\nnewpassword\n" | mysqladmin -uroot password` does not pass the new password to `mysqladmin` command line tool. 
Is there any method to achieve this?

Comment: Just connect using a client and run a query: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new pa$$word';`

Comment: @MattClark thank you. I forgot that method. I will try it